# 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable [Codewars kata 5]

Tags: python-3.x

So i've been trying to complete the challanges on Codewars, currently at the **"The Hashtag Generator"** challange.

Here's the deal:

1. It must start with a hashtag (#).
2. All words must have their first letter capitalized
3. If the final result is longer than 140 chars it must return false.
4. If the input or the result is an empty string it must return false.

I've coded this :

```
def generate_hashtag(s):
    y = s.title()
    t = "#" + y
    if (len(t) <= 140) and s != s.isdigit() and len(s) > 0:
        x = t.replace(" ", "")
        print(x)
    else:
        return False
```

And in the test assesment it can't pass this:

```
generate_hashtag('Do We have A Hashtag')[0]
```

my code return this :

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

how can i fix this ? i've read many example of the error but haven't found an appropriate answer.

PS : when i input the indices inside the paranthesis, it return

```
"#D"
```

and not just "#", why is that ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `[0]` is the subscript and `generate_hashtag` returns `None` when it's successful it just prints. (line 6)

```py
generate_hashtag('Do We have A Hashtag')
>>> #DoWeHaveAHashtag
>>> None

a = generate_hashtag('Do We have A Hashtag')
>>> #DoWeHaveAHashtag
print(a)
>>> None
```

If you want to return a value replace the `print` with a return.

---

As for understanding the `[]` syntax.
When you do  `"abc"[0]` you get `"a"`. You index into the string and return the 0th character. That's what's happening in your other example with D.